# Bentching Ha-Gommel after a Birth

Tags: blessing, women, shiurim-measurements, pregnancy-birth, hagomel

After a woman gives birth many have the custom of reciting the blessing of "ha-gommel" (a blessing of Thanks.) Until how long after a birth may this blessing by recited? (i.e. can it be said even a few months after the birth long after the woman has recovered from the birth itself?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Birkas Hagomel should ideally be recited within three days after becoming obligated to do so. However, if one waited longer than three days, one could still make the beracha for as long as one wishes ([Shulchan Aruch O.C. 219:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14326&st=&pgnum=332)).

The Aruch Hashulchan ([219:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.98_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96)) writes that if so long has past that one no longer remembers one may no longer recite the brocha, but does not put any specific time frame to it. R' Ovadya Yosef (Yabia Omer O.C. 3:16) suggests that since the brocha is in place of the Korban Todah, one should ensure to say it by the first Yom Tov following the salvation (based on [Rosh Hashana 4b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=4b&format=pdf)). Similarly, the Pardes Yosef (Vayikra 7:12) suggests that the time-limit for Ha-gomel is the same as that of a korban: after three festivals have passed.

In the specific case of childbirth, R' Yosef Chaim Zonnefeld ([Salmas Chaim OC 51](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1820&pgnum=37)) ruled that it should be said one week after childbirth.