# Gendered text for Gomel

Tags: blessing, women, grammar-dikduk

related to [Bentching Ha-Gommel after a Birth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20620/bentching-ha-gommel-after-a-birth)
[Do women bentch gomel less often?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77534/do-women-bentch-gomel-less-often)

According to some [opinions](https://jewishaction.com/uncategorized/whats-the-truth-about-a-woman-bentching-gomel/), a woman can say the thanksgiving blessing ("bentch gomel")

The text that one says is

> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה’ אֱלֹהֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם הַגּוֹמֵל לְחַיָּבִים טוֹבוֹת שֶׁגְּמָלַנִי כָּל טוֹב

and what I see listed for the response is

> מִי שֶׁגְמַלְךָ כֹּל טוֹב הוּא יִגְמַלְךָ כֹּל טוֹב סֶלָה

That is written in the masculine, I believe. But if the only one saying the blessing is a woman, would the response be refigured to be in the feminine? I have not found any texts that provide the female construction – if one knows of one, please pass it along.

Comment: Here's one "מי שֶׁגְּמָלֵךְ כֹּל טוֹב הוּא יִגְמָלֵךְ כֹּל טוֹב סֶלָה" first published on Mi Yodeya in this comment. I licence anyone to use it however they want but accept no responsibility

Comment: I don't know where you got that text from, but "כֹּל טוֹב" looks off to me. I'd think it'd be "כָּל־טוֹב". Also, I'd think both מַs would be מָs.

Comment: @msh210 I vaguely recall something about using the _cholam_ or the _kamatz katan_ form regarding וכל החיים יודוך. [R' Emden uses _cholam_](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19725&pgnum=272), while the [Gra advocates the _kamatz katan_](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42980&st=&pgnum=236), but I couldn't understand the reason for their choice when talking about texts without _masorah._

Comment: @msh210 I just copied it from the first website that came up https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/birkat-hagomel-a-jewish-prayer-of-gratitude/